# While migrating Springboot from 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 having Mongo error

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices, multi-tenant

Springboot Version 2.2.1
While migrating from 2.1.0

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2902)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MultiTenancyMongoTemplate.execute(MultiTenancyMongoTemplate.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MultiTenancyMongoTemplate.execute(MultiTenancyMongoTemplate.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultIndexOperations.execute(DefaultIndexOperations.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultIndexOperations.ensureIndex(DefaultIndexOperations.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.(MongoTemplate.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MultiTenancyMongoTemplate.(MultiTenancyMongoTemplate.java:33)
>     at
>   ApplicationsMongoTemplate.(ApplicationsMongoTemplate.java:21)
>     at MongoConfiguration.mongoOperations(MongoConfiguration.java:53)   at
>   MongoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc35c2c4.CGLIB$mongoOperations$1()
>     at
>   MongoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc35c2c4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b7e97015.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>     at
>   MongoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc35c2c4.mongoOperations()
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>     ... 122 more

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "repositories", mongoTemplateRef = "mongoOperations")
public class MongoConfiguration {

    private final MongoClientOptions options;
    private final MongoClientFactory factory;

    public MongoConfiguration(MongoProperties properties,
                                  ObjectProvider<MongoClientOptions> options, Environment environment) {
        this.options = options.getIfAvailable();
        this.factory = new MongoClientFactory(properties, environment);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public MongoClient mongo() {
        return this.factory.createMongoClient(this.options);
    }

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoOperations mongoOperations(final ShareContextMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, final MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
        return new ApplicationsMongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, mongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public ShareContextMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory(final MongoClient mongoClient, final MongoProperties mongoProperties) {
        return new ShareContextMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoProperties.getDatabase());
    }

}
```

```
public class ApplicationsMongoTemplate extends MultiTenancyMongoTemplate implements
    ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

  private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

  public ApplicationsMongoTemplate(
      ShareContextMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory,
      MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
    super(mongoDbFactory, mongoConverter);
  }

  /**
   * Remove the given object from the collection by id.
   *
   * @param object must not be {@literal null}.
   * @return the {@link DeleteResult} which lets you access the results of the previous delete.
   */

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public DeleteResult remove(Object object) {
    Assert.notNull(object, "Object must not be null!");
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new BeforeDeleteEvent(object));
    return super.remove(object);
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationEventPublisher(
      @NonNull ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
  }
}
```

```
build.gradle dependecies

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp"
    compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testCompile "org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:${jmh_version}"
    testCompile "org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:${jmh_version}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${powermock_version}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:${powermock_version}"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3"
    testCompile "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logs that i have found that index is not defined properly in one of your spring managed mongo document. Try checking your **ensureIndex** method and **@CompoundIndex** annotation.